# How to play a set of jpeg files as a movie?

Tags: video-processing

I have a set of jpeg images where each image has an associated description. e.g.

```
im1.jpg - suspect enters bank
im7.jpg - suspect hands teller a note
imj41.jpg - teller gives suspect a bag
...
...
```

It's trivial to view these images individually and see the description but how do I play this as a movie? I need to play the images and when I encounter one with a description, display the description in a status pane.

Do I need to convert the images into a movie, if so how? How do I get the player to notify me when the description frame is encountered?

I'm using Windows. language doesn't matter, I just need the concept right now.

Comment: some info would help:  language? OS? etc.

Comment: Use PowerPoint effects, should work)

Comment: What's the purpose? Do you want to create a web presentation or do you want to use this as an "offline" video/presentation such as Flash or AVI/WMV/whatever?

Comment: We want to show the events as they unfold using a video rather than a set of images. I want to show that a teller hands over a bag of money when a guy put a gun to her face rather than him saying that she was helping him because he was broke.

Comment: wouldn't this be more of a slideshow than a movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# you could take a `Windows Form` with a `PictureBox`. Add a `OpenFileDialog` that allows to select multiple jpg files. Then you could implement a timer that loads the next image after a specified period of time. Before loading the file you could parse the file name. If you find one of your extensions, get the string and manually draw that string onto the `PictureBox`by overwriting the `OnPaint` event.

Comment: This is nice. I never realized that it could be done this simply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can build temp .avi file with opencv and play it as ordinary video file.